# Flutter way to implement clean architecture

Tags: flutter, architecture, clean-architecture

I have started learning flutter after 5 years of android dev. And right now i am trying to implement multi modular clean architecture as i used to, when developing android, example of such architecture: https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture

And i have ran into two issues i can't solve by on my own.

1) What type of flutter module should i use module/plugin/package? I want to make domian layer as simple as it could be(list of interfaces,mappers and dto's), in android it was written in plain kotlin without any android sdk's usage. It seems like domain layer should be package(because it doesn't have any platform specific code and seems to be the simplest module possible) and data layer should be plugin in case i would be forced to make some platform specific code here, but i am not sure. It would be great to have some suggestions here.

2) Maybe there is a github repo example, as I have shown above? All git repos i have found so far are implementing clean architecture with just folders and this approach always ends up with dependencies mess, loosing all the profit you can get from clean architecture.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Ehm, I made it myself, I have two implementations, one with more pain, and one with less, second one is less "clean" but at least flutter is able to build it without me building each module by hands, and then running the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I published [an article](https://medium.com/itnext/flutter-modularized-dependency-injection-4362649f84ed) on using DI container abstractions in a **Modularized Flutter App** adhering to Clean Architecture Principles. The package separation example in the article should give a decent overview of how to divide the solution into packages and organize dependencies between them to adhere to the Clean Architecture principles.

Here are the short answers to your questions:

1. The modules in your solution should be **packages**. It should be Dart-only packages for UI-agnostic layers like `Domain` and Flutter packages for layers like `Presentation/UI`.
2. [This Github repo](https://github.com/Pavel-Sulimau/flutter_modularized_di) is the example implementation of the Counter Flutter app with the solution division into physical Dart/Flutter packages instead of just the folders division. The diagram below depicts the packages you'll see in that example and the dependencies between them. I definitely recommend using physical layer division, i.e. using packages, in any serious Flutter app.

Hope that helps you and others!

[image: The packages used in the example solution]

Answer (score 0):

You could pay attention to the library clean_architecture (https://pub.dev/packages/clean_architecture).
It may be possible to implement a clean architecture not by all the rules, but it brings a certain useful result.

In the near future I will add instructions on how to use it

Comment: I have already did this, but it implements clean architecture using just folders, it is much harder to control dependencies with such implementation. So i am searching for module based implementation.